# Chinese font rendering in iOS

Tags: ios, fonts, cjk, text-rendering

The results when rendering Chinese text in UITableViewCell look pretty bad:
[image: Table View]

I think this is because of the fallback font rendering behaviour: the locale is English, but I'm rendering Simplified Chinese text.

I think this behaviour is because the system Helvetica only has glyphs for certain of the characters in the text.

Is there any way I can set the fallback Chinese font so that it renders English text in Helvetica, but Chinese text in a given font that has all of the Simplified glyphs?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is simulator only. On the device, it looks fine.

Answer (score 2):

It’s because of the wrong language precedence. If you set your preferred language order as `English, 简体中文`, the issue would not be exist.

For example, “允” is a shared character between Chinese and Japanese. If the system doesn’t know the correct language order, it might choose the wrong font for that character, in this case, a Japanese font.